# Architecting Android wearables - Fenix 3

Tags: android, garmin

I am very new to Android Wear Development but I do have good exp with Mobile development. Now I have to program for wearables. First the target is Fenix 3. Fenix 3 is Garmin product and runs on its own OS. I need to develop a project which reads the activities of the user like Heart Rate, current location and whatever the information I can fetch about that user, I need to fetch and send it to the back end.

Now, my questions are as follows

Question 1: what is the best way to architect this?

Currently the idea is mobile app reads data from wearable and mobile app will update the data to server as wearable is not meant to do heavy processes. Or is there a way to update the server directly from wearable?

Question 2: Like Heart Rate, what are the other activities I can track from Fenix 3 watch from the user?

Question 3:  When obtaining GPS coordinates from Fenix 3 watch, should the user be outside of building to fetch the coordinates? I heard so. But in Android Mobile app, 99% of the time we are successful fetching GPS details and current location inside the building

Please update me with these details.

Comment: Fenix 3 development has nothing to do with Android Wear as it does not run Android Wear.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Sorry I got mixed up. Thanks for your time..